# PowerShell: remote command execution and writing to StdError. How to avoid error message?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-remoting

`PowerShell` code snippet:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'ALPHA' -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
  cmd /c C:\Python27\python.exe test.py 
}
```

test.py python script writes some output to StdError, and I believe that's why following error message appears (in red color):

```
WARNING:root:warning
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING:root:warning:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

**Question:** how to prevent this error message from being displayed? Actually, message `WARNING:root:warning` should be displayed, but `NativeCommandError` should not.

Redirecting script output to `$null` doesn't work for me, because script output **should** be displayed.

Something like `cmd /c C:\Python27\python.exe test.py 2>&1` doesn't help, error still appears

The only solution I currently could imagine - redirect output to file, remove these error lines, then print filtered file content to console. But this solution is somewhat crazy, I believe there should be another, 'sane' solution.

Thanks

Comment: How about `cmd /c C:\Python27\python.exe test.py 2>nul`?

Comment: Issue with `2>$null` is that `WARNING:root:warning` _should_ be displayed, I only want get rid of that `NativeError` part

Answer (score 0):

My current solution: modify `Python` code to make it write messages to `StdOut` instead of `StdErr`. Thankfully, in my case this can be done without modifying libraries code (hey, that's `Python`, it's dynamic and thus **extremely extensible**).